# How to remove an element from an array that is inside an object in React JS (ES6)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I would like to remove an element from an array that is inside an object and override that object with the new values. See example below.

```
var obj = {
  a: [1, 2, 3],
  b: [4, 5, 6],
  c: [7, 8, 9]
}
```

I would like to remove the number 5 from `obj` without knowing in which array the element is.

I am trying to update a state in react using the Context API. It should directly return the object itself.

```
case ACTION: return {
  ...state,
  obj: ?
}
```

Expected final result :

```
var obj = {
  a: [1, 2, 3],
  b: [4, 6],
  c: [7, 8, 9]
}
```

Comment: You tagged this `react`, are you using this with state? If so the answer is different as you don't want to mutate the array directly.

Comment: Yes I am using it with ```react``` inside a Context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a new object with updated values, you can use `Object.entries()` to convert the object to entries of [key, value]. Map the entries, and filter the values array, and then convert the entries back to an object with `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const fn = (obj, item) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([k, v]) => [k, v.filter(o => o !== item)])
  )

const obj = {
  a: [1, 2, 3],
  b: [4, 6],
  c: [7, 8, 9]
}

const result = fn(obj, 5)

console.log(result)
```

There is a slight problem here that might cause unnecessary rendering - since we filter all arrays, each array is new, even if the item doesn't exist in that array to start with. We can solve that by check if an array actually contain the item before filtering it. This might be premature optimization, and should be profiled.

```js
const fn = (obj, item) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .map(e => e[1].includes(item) ? [e[0], e[1].filter(o => o !== item)] : e)
  )

const obj = {
  a: [1, 2, 3],
  b: [4, 6],
  c: [7, 8, 9]
}

const result = fn(obj, 5)

console.log(result.c === obj.c) // c didn't change

console.log(result)
```

If `Object.fromEntries()` is not supported by your environment, you can easily replace it with a function based on `Array.reduce()`:

```js
const fromEntries = entries =>
  entries.reduce((obj, [k, v]) => {
    obj[k] = v
  
    return obj
  }, {})

const fn = (obj, item) =>
  fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([k, v]) => [k, v.filter(o => o !== item)])
  )

const obj = {
  a: [1, 2, 3],
  b: [4, 6],
  c: [7, 8, 9]
}

const result = fn(obj, 5)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking. I ran this is vanilla js but is it normal that an error occured in reactjs ```undefined is not a function near Object.fromEntries```?

Comment: `Object.fromEntries()` is supported by all new browsers. It's not supported by IE.

Comment: It's easy to replace `Object.fromEntries()` with a function based on reduce. I'll add an example.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach, IMHO, would be to [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) that array:

```js
obj.b.splice(1, 1);
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't know where the item would be (as per the comment), you could go over them all, and filter each array:

```
const toRemove = 5;
Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
    obj[k] = obj[k].filter(i => i != toRemove);
});
```

Comment: As I said to @plichard, it is my fault, I misspoke. I rather wanted to delete an element entered by the user without really knowing where this element is

Comment: @CustyZ01 so I misunderstood the question them. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but is that returning an object? For example can I do this: ```obj = Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
    obj[k] = obj[k].filter(i => i != toRemove);
});```

I am trying to get back the object to update a react state (see EDIT in question)

Comment: @CustyZ01 this updates `obj` in-place. If you want, you can then return it.

Comment: You could probably do `obj.b.splice(obj.b.indexOf(5), 1)`

Comment: @alexis_thual true, but you'd have to loop over it. That is, unless you assume there can be only one `5` in the array

Comment: @Mureinik I didn't get it. Should I add a return statement inside the forEach? Because when I do ```obj = Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => { return obj[k] = obj[k].filter(i => i != toRemove); });``` I get undefined
***EDIT***: Even without the return

Comment: @CustyZ01 no, I meant you can add `return obj` after this statement.

Comment: Alright I got it! Thank you very much @Mureinik